# Laravel File Upload to GCP Storage - .json files saves as .txt

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform

I'm uploading .json files to a GCP Storage bucket in my Laravel project. File upload is working fine but .json files saves as .txt files.

**Eg:**

filename.json -----> filename.txt

However, when I manually upload these files to the bucket, (via UI of GCP) this is not happening. They upload as they are.

Here's my file upload data

[upload data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOPHW.png)

Here's my code

```
public static function uploadFileToGoogleBucket($uploaded_file, $path)
{
    $disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
    $result = $disk->put($path, $uploaded_file);

    if ($result) {
        $url = $disk->url($result);
    } else {
        $url = null;
    }

    dd($uploaded_file, $url);

    return $url;
}
```

Any idea to fix this weird bug ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Specifically the code snippet of the upload

Comment: Could you add the `dd` function as well? The one you shared is not showing the actual upload of the file.